# to run a command for various variables in shell script

Tags: linux, bash, shell, array

So, i'm storing the values of the first column returned from a sql query in a variable(`var`)..it's supposed to be an array type, because the sql query returns multiple rows, and later,these values would be used in a command.

I'm not sure how to run the same command one after the other with different variables in a shell script.

```
var=`app/oracle/product/10.2.0/bin/sqlplus -s user/passwd<< !EOF!
  set pages 0 echo off feed off timing off
select entity_name,uid,set_date from table_name;
exit
     !EOF!`
```

The command to be run looks like:

```
X=$var Y=`date` ./test.sh
```

Comment: Could you show how you give `var` its value?

Comment: I've edited my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to store the output of your database query in one variable.

```
app/oracle/product/10.2.0/bin/sqlplus -s user/passwd <<END_SQL | while IFS= read -r thing; do X="$thing" Y="$(date)" ./test.sh; done
set pages 0 echo off feed off timing off
select entity_name,uid,set_date from table_name;
exit
END_SQL
```

This would read the output of the `sqlplus` command and call your script once for each line, setting the value of the environment variables `X` and `Y` in the process.

Answer (score 2):

Your request is unclear. Are you in a position to modify the script? If not, and if it explicitly depends on the `X` and `Y` variables, you'll need a temp / loop variable. To run `test.sh` for every array element, try a `for` loop (unless there are white space chars in any of the elements):

```
for TMP in "${var[@]}"; do X="$TMP" Y=$(date) ./test.sh; done
```

Comment: Thanks for the response..`X` and `Y` are the variables that i'm passing to the script: `test.sh`, so basically, the command to be run from the command prompt looks like: `X=$var Y=$(date) ./test.sh`. I'm not sure if in the loop, it'll check the successful completion of it's previous run.